# How to specify a folderpath containing spaces in an environment variable that will be passed to cp in the run script build phase in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, build, whitespace, cp, run-script

I have the following line in a script I am running in the "Run Script" build phase in my Xcode project:

```
cp -v "/Users/myusername/Desktop/foo2Texture5.png" $BACKGROUND_TEXTURES_FOLDER_PATH
```

$BACKGROUND_TEXTURES_FOLDER_PATH is defined as a "User defined setting" in the build settings for my project. This path is generated by combining other variables / user settings etc.

The problem is, that the cp command tends to fail when the folder path contains a "space".
But since the folder path is generated by combining other variables, how can I "escape" the path, so that cp reads the variable properly?

echo seems to output the variable correctly --> So it doesn't seem to have a problem with the space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to surround the entire environment variable with quotes.

Like : "$BACKGROUND_TEXTURES_FOLDER_PATH"